# What does $\tfrac{p}{q}$ represent in this continued fraction question?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, continued-fractions

In this theorem for continued fractions

$\alpha \in \Bbb R /\Bbb Q $ suppose $n >1$ $, 0<q \leq q_n$

$\tfrac{p}{q}\neq\tfrac{p_n}{q_n}$, where $\tfrac{p_n}{q_n}$ is the $n^{th}$ convergent af $\alpha$ then $|\alpha-\tfrac{p_n}{q_n}|<|\alpha-\tfrac{p}{q}|$.

What does $\tfrac{p}{q}$ represent ? Originally I had thought it was $\alpha$ itself but obviously that would make no sense I realised after getting to the inequality at the end.

Comment: Please provide a link, if online, or otherwise a reference, to where the theorem for continued fractions you are asking about comes from. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I can't provide either it's from handwritten lecture notes

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt reply. Have you tried asking the lecturer, or perhaps some of your classmates, about this?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I have a meeting with my lecturer on Wednesday , but I have exams in 2 weeks so I'm trying to get as much covered before I meet her as possible

Comment: It's probably some rational approximation to $\alpha$. It is a well known theorem that simple continued fraction convergents provide the best rational approximation to the limit with denominators of certain size. Which is why here we have $q \leq q_n$ as the condition and the inequality in the end means that the approximation with $p_n/q_n$ is better

Comment: @YuriyS So supposing we have $\alpha=[a_;a_1...a_n….a_k….]$ then the $\tfrac{p}{q}=a_k$ and the $\tfrac{p_n}{q_n}=a_n$ ?

Comment: @excalibirr, no, if $p/q$ was one of the convergents, it would be $p_k/q_k$. It's likely some fraction *not* belonging to the set of convergents

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha$ is an irrational and so it has a sequence of convergents $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ (rational numbers) that approximate $\alpha$ closer and closer.

The statement you quote has as its conclusion that $|\alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n}| < |\alpha-\frac{p}{q}|$, saying that $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is a better approximation of $\alpha$ than $\frac{p}{q}$ is (some other rational). But the condition on this other approximating rational $\frac{p}{q}$ makes no sense: what does it mean that "$\frac{p}{q}$ does not divide $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$"? We usually talk about divisibility in proper rings, but in fields (like $\Bbb Q$) every is divisible by any non-zero element). You might want to check what the lecturer means by that statement (or whether you copied it correctly). Check out the "best rational approximations" part of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) as well.

**After changing the condition in the question:**  After adding $\frac{p}{q} \neq \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ and $q \le q_n$ the world is right again and it's the statement in the Wikipedia page I linked to. So it's saying that the $n$-th convergent is the best rational approximation of $\alpha$ among all fractions of smaller or equal denominator.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was an equals or a does not divide sign it was probably an equals, I'll edit it now. But basically the then the $p/q=a_k$ and the $p_n/q_n=n$ for 
 $\alpha=[a_;a_1...a_n….a_k….]$ then right ?

Comment: @excalibirr No, that notation makes no sense. $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is not $n$, and $\frac{p}{q}$ is probably not one of the convergents $a_k$.

Comment: sorry that was a typo , I meant to write $p_n/q_n=a_n$, the first line of the proof starts of with let $q=q_n$ by the way that's why I thought maybe $p/q$ was one of the convergents. I'll give everything you said a think anyway and read the Wikipedia article , thanks for your advice :)